# How to use OnNotify of generic TList

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe5

I want to use the OnNotify event of a generic TList. Assigning a procedure to OnNotify yields the error message:

```
E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.Generics.Collections.TCollectionNotification' and 'System.Classes.TCollectionNotification'
```

I am declaring a class and in it a generic TList is used as follows:

```
TEditor_Table = class (TObject)
public
  FEditors: TList<TGradient_Editor>;  // List containing the editors
```

This is not the neatest way of doing it but I need this for a test. The list is instantiated in the constructor:

```
constructor TEditor_Table.Create (Owner: TFMXObject);
begin
   inherited Create;

   FEditors := TList<TGradient_Editor>.Create;
   FOwner := Owner;
end; // Create //
```

Next in the main form a function is declared

```
procedure do_editor_change (Sender: TObject; const Item: TGradient_Editor; Action: TCollectionNotification);
```

and the TColor_Editor class is instantiated as follows:

```
FColor_Editor := TEditor_Table.Create (List_Gradients);
FColor_Editor.FEditors.OnNotify := do_editor_change;
                                                   ^
error occurs here----------------------------------+
```

I do not understand the message at all and I am at a los why the compiler seems to confuse the two units: 'System.Generics.Collections.TCollectionNotification' and 'System.Classes.TCollectionNotification'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the RTL defines two different versions of `TCollectionNotification`. One in `System.Classes` and one in `Generics.Collections`.

You are using `TList<T>` from `Generics.Collections` and so need the `TCollectionNotification` from `Generics.Collections`. But in your code `TCollectionNotification` is the version declared in `System.Classes`. That's because, at the point where you write `TCollectionNotification`, `System.Classes` was used after `Generics.Collections`.

Solutions are:

1. Change the order of your uses so that `Generics.Collections` appears after `System.Classes`. This is good practice no matter what. Or,
2. Fully specify the type: `Generics.Collections.TCollectionNotification`.

Comment: You omitted one source of error: having declared System.Classes and not System.Generics.Collections which happened in this case :-) You helped me to find the culprit, thanks! There are some nasty errors associated with this mix up. I'll follow your advice and always declare System.Classes first.

Comment: That's not a source of error. If you omit `Generics.Collections` then you get a different failure. Then your failure is that `TList<T>` is not defined.

Comment: In this situation it is. There was a `system.classes` declaration in the mainform but no `system.generics.collection` that caused the compiler error. The `tlist` is declared in another unit. Adding a system.generics.collection solved the error.

Comment: Well, I couldn't see those details. By the way, making `FEditors` public seems wrong. Is the code really like that?